# Making this tire sidewall?

Tags: materials, vector-mapping

I want to add the Good Year lettering on the side of this vintage racing tire. I know I have to UV unwrap, what I'm not sure of is how to set up the material.

I'm guessing I have to use a bump map to raise the lettering and then a what, color map? To add the coloring. I'm not really sure. I think I know what size to make the graphic (based on another course I did) I'm just not sure how to put it together. Example below.

[image]

Comment: Please include and example of you work with a Blender screen capture.  Please show your wheel as a mesh, texture, and current UV Map. Your current wheel above is a partial view of the side which is less useful rather than a whole image of the side.

Comment: Using Nodes you can easily have the Bump/Height map for the lettering and the colour via a Diffuse BSDF node together. Practice on a separate Blend and the default Cube to get the hang of it. Also note you can unwrap the tire mesh by selecting the faces you want to affect, you do not need to unwrap the entire tire. You can also create n number of unwrapped UVs to work with.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I've gotten the bump map to work so I have the goodyear logo as raised lettering. But I can't figure out how to get the white color on top.

[tire settings here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6r7gcrkkb9ce3ok/tiresetting.png?dl=0)

(Can't seem to add the image here in the comment, exclamation point before not working).

Comment: The information requested above has not been provided.  I will let you do it your way.  You will have success eventually with more research.